# How to bind entity, that I have got from database, to my request's DTO?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a DTO (data transfer object) Class. Maybe it's incorrect name for this class but I usually call it as Request model or DTO and I map data from my JSON request to this class. I'll give you an example:

```
 public class SaveRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("category_id")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to choice category!!!")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to type title!!!")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see I have two properties here. One - is simple `Title` - just a string, but the second - is my database entity. For this project I use Entity framework Core and .NET Core MVC 2.2. I'll show you my database context:

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application> Applications {get; set;}
        ... more props here ...
```

And Category model's code:

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public Category()
        {
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
```

In the controller I have the following method:

```
 public IActionResult Save([FromBody] SaveRequest request) {...}
```

As you can see, here I'm trying to catch `SaveRequest` model.

So, now you know all about my code. This is about my issue. I send the following JSON:

```
{
  "title": "Hello!! How are you!!!",
  "category_id": 777
}
```

I would like to bind `category_id` request param to real `Category` EF entity. I mean, ask EF Framework to find me `Category` with given id, and then bind it to `Category` property in the DTO class. If `Category` entity with given id does not exist than add new model error to model state (to showing it for a client). If it exists, I would like to have it bound to my DTO. I have read this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and I have seen something about `[BindProperty]`, but I dont understand is it suitable for my issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

entity framework can't do that automatically , i think you can build a custom model binder

however, you can do that in your controller

in DTO

```
public class SaveRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("category_id")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to choise category!!!")]
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to type title!!!")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

in your controller

```
public IActionResult Save([FromBody] SaveRequest request) {

   var category = context.categories.where(c => c.id == request.Category_id).FirstOrDefaults();

   if(category == null) 
      return NotFound();
 ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried custom model binder. It is just a pain. Maybe you have an example for my case?